# How to ignore the launcheMode of "SingleTask" when starting an Activity?

Tags: android, launchmode

[image]

There are three Activites where B's launch mode is "SingleTask". I'm wondering How to start a new B rather than restarting the old B when using C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if Activity B is set in the manifest to use `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, there is no way (that I know of) to override this.

However, you could remove this attribute from your manifest and instead use code like this when you *wanted* the `singleTask` behavior:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

The end result is that you get `singleTask` behavior when you want it, and you don't get it when you don't want it. You just have to change the strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in onBack press method of activity

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent BackpressedIntent = new Intent();
    BackpressedIntent .setClass(getApplicationContext(),B.class);
    BackpressedIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(BackpressedIntent );
    finish();
}
```